I an getting an error in my pycharm while runnning chromedriver()
C:\Users\suchi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\suchi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\test\demo.py
There was an error managing chromedriver (error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json)); using driver found in the cache
Error sending stats to Plausible: error sending request for url (https://plausible.io/api/event)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\suchi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\test\demo.py", line 23, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\suchi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in init
super().init(
File "C:\Users\suchi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 55, in init
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\suchi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 102, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
File "C:\Users\suchi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Users\suchi.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64\126.0.6478.182\chromedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
i have tried with reset the path and changed the interpreter.was not able to fix this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
